# Is there an alternative for the Intel WebConsole for managing the RS2WG160 RAID controler on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a server with 16 HDs connected on an Intel RS2WG160 Raid controller and I would very much like to know the state of the disks using the Web Console that Intel provides. The problem is that Ubuntu is not supported and the (very few) info I could gather online on using alien to create a deb package for ubuntu using the rpm for RedHat did not work.

So my question is, is there an alternative for this web console that can give me the info on individual HDs I'm looking for? Or a specific way of installing it?

Thanks for the help!